# contract network feasibility study

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

this is a feasibility study of if this is doable and if so: will it eat 100s of eth in gas just to operate :)

- say i have an ERC1155 contract "stock" that stores clothing items.
- a "wardrobe" contract (i assume ERC1155Receiver) that can receive items from "stock".
- a "customer" contract that creates and keeps the generated "wardrobe"
  contract in a variable and also stores some basic user data.
- a "customersDatabase" contract that stores all those "customer"
  contracts in a mapping or array with simple functionality to filter and search for users.
- and finally a "corp" contract that processes and stores funds forwarded by the "stock" contract

now i'd like to have a web app be able to create such a "customer" contract and add it to the "customersDatabase" and have the user purchase items via the "stock" contract and have Metamask show the contents of the "wardrobe" contract.

i assume this could be kept much simpler using structs but i feel this would be an overall easier to maintain solution if its even doable.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Yes, it seems doable. How much gas it will cost, is hard to say. The storage is usually principal responsible for the cost, but contract interactions also add to it.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! So when a user creates an account (creating a "customer" contract which creates a "wardrobe" contract) it they could enter the resulting address of their "wardrobe" contract into metamask and would see their purchased items right? They should also be able to trade their items in their own "wardrobe" contract on regular marketplaces then if i am not mistaken?

Comment: Metamask is quiete basic, it only show information of some important tokens, and I think some Nfts. I will not show information about a contract it can't recognize. You could always provide an app that connects to metamask and uses it to query the contract details. The other details depends on the contract and the markets, some of them accepts Nfts that follow eip 721/1155, etc. If you have more question it will be better to create a separate one.